# Modificar un valor (total a pagar) en funcion a la cantidad de productos

Tags: javascript

Muy buenas tardes.
Mi pregunta es en relacion a js basico, estoy aprendiendo a programar y me he topado con una gran problematica por falta de conocimientos;

Tengo la tipica card de un carrito de compras en donde al hacer click en un boton suma +1 a la cantidad y a hacer click en otro boton suma -1. he logrado que los botones funcionen de manera correcta con funciones basicas, ahora necesito tomar el valor actual de la cantidad de productos y mutiplicarlo por un valor fijo (declarado en una const) y que muestre el "valor total" en otro parrafo creado en el html;

actualmente este es el codigo de los botones, pero no logro dar con la solucion para poder multiplar el valor de la const precio, con la cantidad actual de productos.

```
const precio = 400000

document.querySelector(".precio-inicial").innerHTML = precio


function sumar(){
    let plus = document.querySelector(".cantidad");
    let amountplus = parseInt(plus.innerHTML);
    plus.innerHTML = amountplus +1
}

function restar(){
    let minus = document.querySelector(".cantidad");
    let amountminus = parseInt(minus.innerHTML);
    minus.innerHTML = amountminus -1
}
```

Este es mi intento para crear la multiplicacion del total por el valor;

```
let total = document.querySelector(".valor-total");
let totalamount = parseInt(document.querySelector(".cantidad").innerHTML);
let value = parseInt(precio);
total.innerHTML = totalamount * value;
```

Muchas gracias de antemano por darse el tiempo de leer mi solicitud.
Que tengas buen dia

Comment: coloca el HTML a la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola!

Si he entendido bien, prueba esto a ver si te funciona.

Para calcular el valor total y mostrarlo en el otro párrafo que has preparado para eso, **necesitas actualizar el cálculo**. Puedes crear una **función que se llama cuando se realiza un cambio en la cantidad de productos**, ya sea sumando o restando un producto. Aquí hay una forma de hacerlo:

```
<!-- Primero, asegúrate de que el HTML tenga un elemento para mostrar el valor total, span, div o cualquiera -->
   <p>Valor total: <span class="valor-total">0</span></p> 

<!-- Después, crea una función para actualizar el total y modifica las funciones sumar y restar para calcular el valor total y actualizarlo cuando se haga clic-->
   <script>
      const precio = 400000;

      document.querySelector(".precio-inicial").innerHTML = precio;
      let cantidad = document.querySelector(".cantidad");
      let total = document.querySelector(".valor-total");

      function actualizarTotal() {
         let amount = parseInt(cantidad.innerHTML);
         let value = parseInt(precio);
         total.innerHTML = amount * value;
      }

      function sumar() {
         let amountplus = parseInt(cantidad.innerHTML);
         cantidad.innerHTML = amountplus + 1;
         actualizarTotal();
      }

      function restar() {
         let amountminus = parseInt(cantidad.innerHTML);
         if (amountminus > 0) {
            cantidad.innerHTML = amountminus - 1;
            actualizarTotal();
         }
      }
   </script>
```

La función *actualizarTotal* se encarga de **calcular el valor total multiplicando la cantidad de productos por el precio de la constante, y luego actualiza** el contenido del elemento HTML que tiene clase valor-total.

Las funciones sumar y restar llaman a *actualizarTotal* después de cambiar la cantidad de productos para **actualizar el valor total** cada vez que se haga clic en los botones de suma o resta.

Espero haberte ayudado, ¡un saludo!